# Remove time from toTimeString()?

Tags: javascript

```
var d = new Date();
var region = "**Region** - `" + d.toTimeString();
```

I am currently using this code, which returns...

```
**Region** - `09:39:43 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)`
```

I was wondering if there was any possible way to actually remove the time (09:39:42) from the string so I can just have "GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)". I've looked for a while on the internet now and have found nothing that applies to this. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Regular Expressions did the trick, however, I have update the code since I asked this question a while ago and used a substring instead, shortening the code drastically.

Comment: replace using regex? `.toTimeString().replace(/\d+:\d+:\d+\s+/, '')`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes! It worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.replace` and replace matching string with whatever you want, in this case an empty string.

```js
    let date = '09:39:43 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)';
    let regex = /\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/;
    let newDate = date.replace(regex, '');
    
    console.log(`${date}\n${newDate}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the string, you could do that with a simple `split()`, `shift()` and `join()` if you're assured that the format is always the same :

```
var d = new Date();
var regionTmp = d.toTimeString().split(' ');
regionTmp.shift();
var Region = "**Region** - `" + regionTmp.join(' ') + "`";
```

Comment: Please coomment what's wrong with the answer when you downvote